# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region about the y-axis;

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, solid-of-revolution

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified axis.

$y=x^{-5}, y=0, x=1, x=9;$

about the $y$-axis.

How do I solve this when given four values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the method of cylindrical shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration):

$$
V=2\pi\int_{1}^{9}x\frac{1}{x^5}\,dx=2\pi\int_{1}^{9}x^{-4}\,dx
$$